# Write a number as the sum of two squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, sums-of-squares

I am trying to write $82900$ as a sum of two squares. I am given a hint that $8290 = 57^2 + 71^2$. How can I use this hint to set up the problem? I have used Fermat's Descent in the past, can I still use this here?

Comment: Well, $10=3^2+1^2$.  Do you know how to write $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)$ as a sum of two squares?

Comment: Consider the complex number $z = (57+71 i)(3 + i),  |z| = | (57+71 i) | |(3 + i)| = (8290)(10)$

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: @rabito FYI, see [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity).

Comment: @rabito You can answer your own question here, and accept the answer, so that the question does not remain on the unanswered queue. Or you can just delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$8290 \cdot 10 = (57^2 + 71^2)(10)$

$82900 = (57^2 + 71^2)(1^2 + 3^2)$

Rewrite using Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity

$(57 + 213)^2+(171-71)^2$

$270^2 + 100^2 = 82900$